# PHP7 compatibility with Symfony3?

Tags: php-7, symfony

With the release of both [PHP7](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.php) and [Symfony3](http://symfony.com/blog/symfony-3-0-0-released) this week, have Symfony3 been developed with PHP7 in mind?

To put it another way, if we have PHP7 installed and are starting a new Symfony3 project from scratch, do we run the risk of facing migration problems from within the Symfony framework?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

PHP 7 is mostly [backward compatible](http://php.net/manual/de/migration70.incompatible.php) with 5.x versions. Most of the changes that are incompatible with previous versions consist of the removal of quirky features anyway. This is usually not the type of stuff SF developers tend to use.

And, yes, SF3 [has been developed with PHP7](http://symfony.com/blog/symfony-achieves-100-php7-compatibility) (and HHVM, by the way) in mind.

Answer (score 0):

PHP 7 is backwards compatibly unless a featured has been deprecated. Symfony3 is 100% PHP 7 compatible and is built using PHP 7.

Comment: PHP7, the new version of the programming language Symfony is built with, will be released at the end of the year. Source: http://symfony.com/blog/symfony-achieves-100-php7-compatibility